# What is the reason behind the shape of the magnetic field lines in a circular loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Sorry if this question is stupid, but I really need to understand this. I read that in a straight simple wire, the magnetic field lines are concentric about the wire, and the circles become larger as we move away from the wire. Now lets think about a circular wire. All I can think about is the wire making many of these circles around the curve, kind of like a spring. But if we look at the diagram of the field lines around a loop, they gradually become straight, and through the centre of the loop, the field line is perfectly straight. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Did you mean as in [this diagram](https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/MagParticle/Physics/CoilField.htm)?

Comment: If you understand how the magnetic field forms around a single conductor carrying current then merely by considering symmetry of a circular conductor you can imagine the correct form of the field.  Hint:  the opposite sides of the circular current (opposite sides of circle) are moving in opposite directions (assuming simplification of DC).  Use the right-hand-rule and sketch out the field lines and you can begin to see that the fields in the middle of the circular current are almost straight lines (circular current much larger than diameter of conductors).

Comment: I assume you're asking for some kind of real geometrical description of the field lines. This is going to be impossible to answer unless you tell us your physics and math background. There is no elementary, nonmathematical way to answer this. Or if all you want is a qualitative characterization of the field pattern, please edit the question to say so.

Comment: @K7PEH: Are you claiming that the field lines are circles? They're not.

Comment: I believe only that I was talking about a circular conductor, not circular magnetic field lines.  Wow, did it really take 3 1/2 years for a rebuttal comment?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
<sub>(source: [gsu.edu](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/imgmag/curloo.gif))</sub>

Do you know a straight line is a circle with infinite radius.

Similarly at centre you get a circle with infinite radius.

When wire is bent in form of circle, magnetic field is no more concentric circles. Electric field at centre of ring is much stronger than outside. This causes field to form ovals.

The oval in centre can bend in neither direction, so it forms a circle with infinite radius, i.e. a straight line..

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, unless the OP is satisfied with an answer that doesn't say anything about the actual shape.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, remember that a coil is just a way in which a piece of straight wire can be bunched up so as to magnify its inductance. Regarding your example, per K7PEH's comment it has to do with the geometry of a linear coil, which is called a *solenoid* (hint hint, *search term*). For a solenoid of "sufficient" length, there will exist a zone inside the solenoid where the magnetic field lines are bunched together and are straight lines, or nearly so.

Answer (score -2):

Consider a circular current loop has a radius **R**,

As shown in the image

[image]

The magnetic field lines won't pass through the exact center of the loop because every side of the coil will fight for the center and you should remember that the field lines won't intersect.so,any of the field lines won't pass through the exact center.

Let us consider a particle of radius r<<**R** whose center is denoted by **O** which is concentric with the circular current loop,even though the field lines don't pass through the center which is **O** but the non-intersecting(parllel) field lines will pass on the area covered by the particle exept the center.so,the tangential vectors which is large in number pass through the particle will add up and form a long vector which is straight line.

Now you may ask that "why does the tangential vector at the near center alone form a long straight vector.why, not other "

Because no other region have that much field intensity that as the near center.

Hope you understand...

Comment: This 7 year old question already has 2 answers that are adequate. Your answer does not provide any additional clarity. The statement that field lines don't pass through the exact centre is not correct. The statement "Because no other region have that much field intensity that is flux as the near center" does not make much sense, and does not explain why the field lines are straight in the middle.

Comment: Please explain your comment in detailed manner